# Diameter of $n$-unit-vector closed scribble

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, random-walks

Suppose one creates a random, closed, likely self-crossing polygon
from $n$ unit-length vectors arranged head-to-tail,
randomly oriented except for the requirement
that their sum is zero (so the polygon closes).
Here are some examples, for $n=36$:

---

[image: FlipPoly8]

---

> **Q**. What is the expected diameter of such a polygon, as a function of $n$?
>   In particular, what is the expected growth rate w.r.t. $n$?

Perhaps it is expected to be $\sim \sqrt{n}$? Continuing the example above,
I see about $1.1 \sqrt{n}$. But that could also be about $0.2 n$ if the growth is
linear instead. 
My limited simulations do not distinguish between
square-root and linear growth.

---

To answer *guest*'s query, I start with a closed regular polygon, and then reflect
subchains across the line determined by randomly selected pairs of vertices, until
thorough mixing is reached.

Comment: What exactly does 'randomly oriented except for the requirement that their sum is zero' mean, and how are you sampling from that distribution?

Comment: @guest: Good question! Maybe I should answer directly in the post...

Comment: that sounds like a 2d analogue of the crankshaft algorithm for 3d sampling... did you invent that sampling scheme yourself or find it in the literature?  I would guess that if it's in the literature and is proved to be ergodic then they would also give other properties like the one you are requesting

Comment: @guest: Invented myself, in ignorance of the literature. :-)

Comment: When $n$ grows, the polygon becomes a Brownian bridge (also called Brownian loop). The Brownian bridge is obtained by a linear deformation of Brownian motion. Since the frontier of Brownian motion has [Hausdorff dimension 4/3](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0010165) and as its size scales as $\sqrt n$, a reasonable conjecture is that the frontier scales as $n^{2/3}$. Is that compatible with your simulations ?

Comment: @V.Rossetto: Definitely that is compatible! I will try to run more extensive simulations when time permits. Your comment is in some sense an "answer" to my query, for which I am grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I post yesterday's comment as an answer and add a remark concernin the area)

When $n$ grows, the polygon becomes a Brownian bridge (also called Brownian loop). The Brownian bridge is obtained by a linear deformation of Brownian motion. Since [the frontier of Brownian motion has Hausdorff dimension 4/3](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0010165) and as its size scales as $\sqrt n$, a reasonable conjecture is that the frontier scales as $n^{2/3}$.

Your algorithm, if it already can identify the frontier, should also be able to compute the enclosed area. There is a result that this area should have expectation value $n\pi/5$ that would be interesting to check !
See the article by [Garban and Ferreras](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00220-006-1555-2?LI=true).

Comment: I am puzzled by this answer.  I would have expected the diameter to behave like the maximum of partial sums of random vectors of unit length, which would be roughly $n^{1/2}$.  Are you saying that the diameter in this case is substantially bigger, just because of the constraint that the end points have to match?  Seems quite strange (and interesting of course).

Comment: @Lucia. The segments of unit length create a shape in the plane, they can intersect each other eventually. Take a point $M$ very far away from the figure. All the points that you cannot reach from $M$ without crossing a segment form a bounded domain $\mathcal D$. The polyogon is the boundary of $\mathcal D$. By *perimeter* we mean the length of the polygon, which is made of segments of various lengths between 0 and 1. The *size* or *diameter* is, form instance, the maximum distance between two points inside $\mathcal D$ and it indeed scales as $\sqrt n$.

Comment: Indeed.  Note that the problem asks about the diameter and not the perimeter.  Hence my confusion about your answer.  I agree that the diameter scales as $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @Lucia. You are right. Maybe I interpreted the question with the assumption that it cannot be that simple.